# Magento 2 print phtml product collection

Tags: magento2, collection

When I try to get product list in a controller for a ajax module like this :

```
echo $this->layoutFactory->create()
            ->createBlock('\Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ListProduct')
            ->setCollection($productCollection)
            ->setTemplate('Magento_Catalog::product/list.phtml')
            ->toHtml();
```

I have this error :
Fatal error: Uncaught Error:

```
Call to a member function setData() on bool in /var/www/magento2/vendor/magento/module-catalog/Block/Product/ListProduct.php:419 Stack trace: 
#0 /var/www/magento2/vendor/magento/module-catalog/Block/Product/ListProduct.php(391): Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ListProduct->getPriceRender() 
#1 /var/www/magento2/generated/code/Magento/Catalog/Block/Product/ListProduct/Interceptor.php(180): Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ListProduct->getProductPrice(Object(Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Interceptor)) 
#2 /var/www/magento2/app/design/frontend/Vital/vital/Magento_Catalog/templates/product/list.phtml(121): Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ListProduct\Interceptor->getProductPrice(Object(Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Interceptor)) 
#3 /var/www/magento2/vendor/magento/framework/View/TemplateEngine/Php.php(59): include('/var/www/magent...') 
#4 /var/www/magento2/vendor/magento/module-developer/Model/TemplateEngine/Decorator/DebugHints.php(46): Magento\Framework\View\TemplateEngine\Php->render(Object(Magento\Catal in /var/www/magento2/vendor/magento/module-catalog/Block/Product/ListProduct.php on line 419
```

Does anyone know where the problem is coming from and how to solve it?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

For load product collection, you can take reference from below code:

```
protected $_productCollectionFactory;
    
public function __construct(
    \Magento\Backend\Block\Template\Context $context,        
    \Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\CollectionFactory $productCollectionFactory,        
    array $data = []
)
{    
    $this->_productCollectionFactory = $productCollectionFactory;    
    parent::__construct($context, $data);
}

public function getProductCollection()
{
    $collection = $this->_productCollectionFactory->create();
    $collection->addAttributeToSelect('*');
    $collection->setPageSize(3); // fetching only 3 products
    return $collection;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your response but my problem is not on load product list it's on print phtml of product list using ajax.